# Optimization problem calculus 1

Tags: calculus, optimization

I always have trouble setting up the problem. I do not know what formulas I will need. I know volume is the constraint and surface area is what I have to find which have to be as small as possible.

a rectangular box without top is to be constructed so that its base is three times as long as it is wide, the box is to have a volume of 2250 cubic inches. find the dimension of the box so that its surface area will be as small as possible.

Comment: When you do this sort of problems: do a list of the variables, try to find as many equations as there are variables or (n-1 equations, to have a variable depending on another, thus you do calculus here). Squeeze the information. For instance you know that:  

- $b=3w$,  
- $bwh=2250$,  
- $2wh+2bh+wb=S $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Detailed) hint: Let the dimensions of the base be $x$ and $y$, and the height be $z$. You know that one of $x$ and $y$ is three times the other; suppose that $x$ is smaller, and write $y$ in terms of $x$. Now write down a formula for the volume of such a box. Finally, what is the surface area? There is one bottom of area $xy$, two sides of area $xz$, and two of area $yz$. So write the surface area in terms of $x$ and $z$.

Now you have an equation for the volume, $2250$, in terms of $x$ and $z$. Use that to write $z$ in terms of $x$, substitute into the surface area, and minimize.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The dimensions of the box are $x,3x,y,$ where $x,3x$ correspond to the basis and $y$ is the height. Since you know the volume, it is $2250=3x^2y,$ or $y=\frac{2250}{3x^2}=\frac{750}{x^2}.$

The area is $3x^2$ (basis) plus $6xy+2xy=8xy$ (lateral area). That is, area $=3x^2+8xy.$

So the problem reduces to study the minimum of $$s(x)=3x^2+8xy=3x^2+8x\frac{750}{x^2}=3x^2 +\frac{6000}{x}.$$